# The better way of bundle Vue.js, cross-env or config.js?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I bundle my sources with webpack at my Vue.js project.

I understand I have 2ways.

#### 1. cross-env

package.json:

```
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
```

#### 2. webpack.{prod|dev}.config.js

package.json:

```
"build": "webpack --progress --hide-modules --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js",
```

webpack.prod.conf.js made by the command

```
vue init webpack
```

I think 2. is the better in the present.
Because I wanna use {prod|dev}.env.js. for a several env variables.

But I don't know the way to bundle them into a few files(like bundle.js) instead of app.[chunkhash].js on 2.

**Which is popular in general?**

To confusion, Webpack4 published on this Febrary.
CommonChunk seems to drop on it.
I think webpack recommends using "--mode" option. But

```
vue init webpack
```

command does not seem to catch up it yet.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I moved my source to new project yarn based.
So I can use webpack4 and "--mode" option.

That aside, I choose env variables via "--env" option and webpack.config.js.

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --env.ENV=local", // local-pc
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development --env.ENV=dev", // dev-server
    "build:stg": "webpack --mode production --env.ENV=stg", // stg-server
    "build:prd": "webpack --mode production --env.ENV=prd" // prd-server
  },
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = env => {
  if (env.ENV === 'local') {
    envs = {
      ENV: '"local"',
      HOST: '"http://localhost:8080/"',
    }
  } else if (env.ENV === 'dev') {
    envs = {
      ENV: '"dev"',
      HOST: '"http://localhost/"',
    }
  } else if (env.ENV === 'stg') {
    envs = { ... }
  } else if (env.ENV === 'prd') {
    envs = { ... }
  }

  return {
    ...
    plugins: [].concat([
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': envs,
      }),
    ]),
  }
}
```

And I can use env variables in my source like:

```
console.log('host：%s', process.env.HOST)
```

To start:

```
yarn dev
```

or

```
yarn build:dev
```

etc.

Comment: mmm...Karma seems to not recognize module.exports when it's a function.